# Search XML for Variable Attribute Using Python & ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have an XML that looks like this (simplified):

```
<file id="file-10">
  <clip>1</clip>
  <timecode>1:00:00:00</timecode>
</file>
<file id="file-11">
  <clip>2</clip>
  <timecode>2:00:00:00</timecode>
</file>
```

I'm trying to use ElementTree to search for a file element with a particular id attribute.
This works:

```
correctfile = root.find('file[@id="file-10"]')
```

This does not:

```
fileid = 'file-10'
correctfile = root.find('file[@id=fileid]')
```

I get:

> SyntaxError: invalid predicate

Is that a limitation of `ElementTree`? Should I be using something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "SyntaxError: invalid predicate"

`file[@id=fileid]` is an invalid XPath expression because you miss the quotes around the attribute value. If you put the quotes around the `fileid`: `file[@id="fileid"]` the expression would become valid, but it is not gonna find anything since it would search for the `file` elements with `id` equals to *"fileid" string*.

Use *string formatting* to insert the `fileid` value into the XPath expression:

```
root.find('file[@id="{value}"]'.format(value=fileid))
```